# retrieve excel data from closed workbook with ado

Tags: excel, vba

I use the following macro to retrieve data from closed workbook. Why the debug.print returns the data to the imediate window, but the data does not copy to the worksheet neither with the statement, `ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset objrecordset![Name] & " " & objrecordset![Number]` ,nor with the statement,`ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1).CopyFromRecordset objrecordset`

```
sub adoExcel()

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objrecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

'*************************************************************************************
objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
"Data Source=C:\Users\sp\Desktop\test ado excel\test.xls;" & _
"Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"
'*************************************************************************************

objrecordset.Open "Select * FROM [Sheet1$]", _
objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

'*************************************************************************************
' Loop through the recordset and send data to the Immediate Window

objrecordset.MoveFirst

Do
    Debug.Print objrecordset![Name] & " " & objrecordset![Number]
    objrecordset.MoveNext
Loop Until objrecordset.EOF

'**************************************************************************************
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset objrecordset![Name] & " " & objrecordset!            [Number]
'**************************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 1):

When you attempt to `CopyFromRecordset` you are already at the end-of-file (EOF) so there is no data to copy. Move the `CopyFromRecordset` statement earlier in your code, before looping through it.

And the argument for this method is a RecordSet object:

```
.CopyFromRecordset objrecordset
```